# How do I insert a decimal in postgres sql

Tags: postgresql, insert, decimal

I am trying to insert into a numeric column a decimal but I keep getting an error.
Below is my statement

INSERT INTO blse VALUES (2082.7, 'Total Nonfarm' ,'Alabama','01/31/2020');

it basically says i need to cast this statement. I do not know what I am doing wrong.. I am beginner taking this class.

and this is the error:

[image: error you get when supplying a number for a date]

Comment: Looks like your columns are in the wrong order, it's expecting the date to come first. You can tell it what order you're inserting the records with code like INSERT INTO blse(amount, name, region, date) VALUES (2082.7, 'Total Nonfarm' ,'Alabama','01/31/2020');

Comment: What error? There is no error message in your topic, in your question

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended that you specify the columns in an `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO tab (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES (val1, val2, val3);
```

That way, you can be certain what value is inserted where.

Since you didn't do that, the first value in the `VALUES` clause gets inserted into the first table column, which is of type `date`. That causes the error you observe.